# PowerShell to filter file size

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script using PowerShell to get file size 0kb as mentioned below

```
$FileExists1 = 'C:\Users\iskandar\Desktop\TEST\*\test0700.txt'

IF (Test-Path $FileExists1) {
    If ((Get-Item $FileExists1).length -gt 0kb) {
      Write-Output "All file size is good!"
    }

Else {
      Write-Output " There is a file with 0KB, Please inform support staff"
    }
}
```

if there is multiple folder with multiple file, the script not filter the 0KB file.

for example : lets say I have 30 files and only one file with 0KB, when I run those script, it shows "All file size is good!".

Can anyone advice?. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$files=gci "C:\Users\iskandar\Desktop\TEST" -file -Recurse | where Length -le 0Kb | select -First 1

if ($files.Count -gt 0)
{
    "There is a file with 0KB, Please inform support staff"
}
else
{
    "All file size is good!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Esperento57 has provided a working solution, let's see what is wrong in the original code.

The problem happens as you are hit by object mismatch. Multiple objects have same attributes that contain different things.

For a single file, `Get-Item` will return a `FileInfo` object that contains file's size in its `.Length` attribute.

For multiple files, `Get-Item` will return an array of `FileInfo` objects. Its  `.Length` attribute contains the length of the array itself. Thus the statement

```
If ((Get-Item $FileExists1).length -gt 0kb) {
```

actually is processed as pseudocode

```
if ($FileExists1-the-array contains more than 0 elements) {
```